# Accessing a variable which belong to another function in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

Please take it easy on me.   I'm a newbie and is trying to learn mapkit.  Just wondering if you can help me find my way with this one.. I have a function which find the coordinate in AppViewController.m

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
  {

  CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [newLocation coordinate];
  NSString *lat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", loc.latitude];
  latitude.text = lat;
  ...

}

My question is, is there a way I can access the variable lat, say something like declaring it as a global varaible, from function - (void) viewDidLoad { ... }

This might sound a stupid question for most of you, but please give me a hint.. I've been reading about singleton.. but couldn't understand how I can use implement this in this one.

Kind Regards,
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make `lat` an instance variable. Declare it in your class's `@interface` section, then you can access it from any method inside the class.

```
@interface AppViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *lat;
}

...

@end
```

Comment: Hi Ole,  thank you for your reply.  I did try that too but when I try to use lat in - (void) viewDidLoad { ... } the value of lat is null;  Any further suggestion?

Comment: Sure, probably because viewDidLoad is called first.